# Which pronoun is appropriate when the subject of a dependent clause is implied?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

The context is:

> The point always is to remember what it was to be **[me/myself]**.
>
> - Joan Didion

The writer is addressing herself here, so that the subject of remembering is implied. The original text uses the object pronoun **me**. I suspect this may be wrong.

Comment: Why do you think “me” is not the correct pronoun here?

Comment: Are you sure that "to remember" has a subject? People often say "Be yourself," so I'd end the sentence with *myself*. But I wouldn't change a published text.

Comment: _Be oneself_ is an idiom means to project one's personality. It works for all personal pronouns -- _Just be yourself and you won't have any trouble_, It's not appropriate for the kind of serious reflection of the quotation. Didion is a poet in any event, and therefore has a license to use pronouns any way she pleases.